# ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
CREATE TABLE employee (

employee_id INT,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(20),
birth_date DATE,
sex VARCHAR(1),
salary INT,
super_id INT,
branch_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY(employee_id)
);


INSERT INTO employee VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250,000, 2, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `comma(,)` from your salary value - it's datatype is int

```
INSERT INTO employee
VALUES(100, 'David', 'Wallace', '1967-11-17', 'M', 250000, 2, 1)
```