# SQL UPDATE: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I know this question is not [new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54997139/er-wrong-value-count-on-row-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1), but it has never been answered for an UPDATE statement.

I have the following error:

```
update `Employees` set `pronoun` = 'Frau', `first_name` = 'Sarah', `last_name` = 'Sallison', `pk_number` = 'HDSU283', `cost_center_id` = 2, `roles_id` = NULL, `start_date` = '2016-11-01', `switch` = 0, `end_date` = NULL, `office_id` = 2, `d_number` = NULL, `vk` = NULL, `employment_type_id` = 1, `service_provider_id` = NULL where `id` = 767
```

> ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

With the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Employees` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pronoun` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `first_name` text,
  `last_name` text,
  `employment_type_id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `service_provider_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pk_number` text,
  `office_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost_center_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `switch` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `e_mail` text,
  `phone` text,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_updated_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mentor_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `vk` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `roles_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `d_number` text,
  `opt_mentoring` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1176 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I don't even understand how this error is possible, if not a column doesn't exist, on an UPDATE STATEMENT.

Comment: There exists some BEFORE UPDATE or AFTER UPDATE trigger on this table, is it? Check for its correctness.

Comment: If you write it as solution, you will get the "Accept" from me. ;-)
Thank you! I am an idiot!

Comment: This is obvious problem. Your error message can be generated only for INSERT. But your query is UPDATE. Hence, this UPDATE causes some INSERT execution. The only place where this is possible is a trigger. Simple logic and nothing else.

Comment: More logic. 99% that INSERT in your trigger have not specified definite columns list of the table where the data should be inserted into (do this never - always add columns list!), and this table structure was altered. 1% - that this was the most first UPDATE on your table after the trigger creation.

Comment: This is due to a program building the statement. If I could access the statement here I would. I reproduced it with simple SQL Query directly on the database and had the same problem.

Comment: *If I could access the statement here I would.* This is possible. You must temporarily enable MySQL [General Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html), execute your program, then disable GL and look for all statements received by MySQL from your application.